# Using maps in Presto

Tags: presto

I'm trying to use Presto's map functionality and am running into some difficulties.  Hopefully someone can set me straight.

I have a table `map_table` with two columns, `k` and `v` which I would like to turn into a map to use in a query.

`WITH my_map AS(
SELECT map(
    (SELECT array_agg(k) FROM map_table),
    (SELECT array_agg(v) FROM map_table)
    ) as m
)
SELECT
    transform(
       list_column,
       x -> my_map[x]
    ) as stuff
FROM
    second_table`

This obviously won't work, since technically I would have to `(SELECT m FROM my_map)` instead of just calling the CTE directly by its name in the query.  But then I'm not allowed to call subqueries inside of a lambda expression.

So what do I do here? Am I just hosed?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I totally follow the question, but have some suggestions.  For the `my_map` CTE, use `map_agg`.  For the rest, I think you just want to attach the map to every row of `second_table`, so you can use it as a lookup.  So, something like:

```
WITH my_map AS(
    SELECT map_agg(k,v) AS m 
    FROM map_table
),
second_table_with_map AS(
    SELECT *, (SELECT m FROM my_map)
    FROM second_table 
)
SELECT
    transform(
       list_column,
       x -> m[x]
    ) as stuff
FROM
    second_table_with_map
```

Comment: Yeah that was what I did; but, Presto throws an error when I left join the map in.  I think the row size is too large, as it's throwing `com.facebook.presto.operator.PageTooLargeException: Remote page is too large`. This lead me to wonder whether I was using this functionality correctly.  Essentially I just want to keep a map around as a hashmap.